# White screen for Camera via LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

Sorry to post a wall of text here but I'm not sure what else to do.

I think this will have something to do with the lack of CameraPreview in the manifest but I'm not sure and also do not know how to add it to the manifest as it extends View. Anyway, the application is targeted to the appropriate sdk for my device, runs and then simply displays a white screen and the "capture" button. I've tried using a SurfaceView instead but then I can't add mpreview to the view. Very confused and would appreciate any help or pointers. Thank you.

CameraActivity.java:

```
package installation04.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private CameraManager mManager;
private String[] mCameraIds;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

LinearLayout camera_preview;
Button button_capture;

public CameraActivity() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    button_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    if(checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())){
        getCameraInstance();
    }

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    LinearLayout preview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}

private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void onClick() {
    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

CameraPreview.java:

```
package installation04.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraPreview extends View  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview: ";
private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CameraPreview(Context cameraActivity, Camera camera){
    super(cameraActivity);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    if (mHolder != null) {
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
}

private SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
    return null;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:viewandroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
package="installation04.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not clear what you are asking, if you don't want preview and instead want a white screen don't add prieview.

```
//remove this line from on create
 preview.addView(mPreview);
```

and give white background to  layout